# Is there anything in our scriptures where it says something similar to "As a man thinketh in his heart, so is he"

Tags: puranas, philosophy, bhagavad-gita, practice, upanishads

I've read the major parts of the Bhagavad Gita where my interpretation is that 'Anyone who is attached to the FRUITS of the reward, he will dwell in misery always'.

Now I'm reading many books like 'The Power of the Subconscious Mind', where it says, you will only attract whatever you think. It quotes a lot from the Bible. This, based on my limited knowledge of my scripture (the Bhagavad Gita), makes me think that this whole Power of Attraction is non-sense.

Is there anything in the other scriptures where it has been hinted that your future is created by your thinking?

Comment: Related or Possible duplicate of [Source of the Shloka Yad bhavam tad bhavathi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24626/3500)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Such a saying is there in the Skanda-Purana (Avani/RevA-Khanda (5),chapter 227

> yādṛśī bhāvanā yasya siddhirbhavati tādṛśī ॥ 227.20 ॥
>
> One gets fruit according to one's own bhAvana (thinking).
>
> Reference : [Wikisource](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AB_(%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE_%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%AD)

So this does mean that one's future is created by his/ her own thinking.