# Do You Take On The Qualities Of The Form You Meditate On?

Tags: gods, goddess

Am often coming across this advice from Hindu texts in different stories.

Like if you want be very strong body, meditate on Hanuman. He was strongest.

If you want to be very smart, meditate on Maa Saraswati.

Does a person take on the qualities of the God/Goddess they meditate on ?

Comment: I've also heard this many times. Could you give some examples of the stories which you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Two Sutras: [*devo bhūtvā devaṁ yajet*](https://archive.org/details/gandharv-tantra/page/n203/mode/2up)— which means in order to worship a god you must become god-like. It is not enough to make offerings and sing praises you need to imbibe divine qualities like compassion, kindness, non-violence, goodness, generosity etc & [*yad bhāvaṃ tad bhavati*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/source-of-the-shloka-yad-bhavam-tad-bhavathi)- What you meditate upon you become. So by constantly thinking of a certain thing you will become that very thing.

Comment: @Rāmachandra Thx ! That makes sense 

Comment: @LSSJBroly I can’t remember specific places this was said, I’m huge Hindu mytho addict so I’m learning from different stories for many years. Feel like I must’ve heard this idea hundreds of times stated in different mythological tales. Vaguely remembering Madhav telling Bhim to meditate on Hanuman for being physically strong in Mahabharath I think ? And then Narad telling this to some devotees somewhere. There must be so many other examples though. I remember Narayan telling this also, to some persons.

Comment: Ok @devibhakt thanks.